# How to update my local branch of fork with original repository from which i forked the master branch of local repository?

Tags: git, github

Suppose i clone from a repository **foo**

I get a local copy name **my/foo**

I then create a branch **mybranch/foo** .
Then i made some commits into **mybranch/foo** while some PR's get merged in **foo** remote repository( remote repository ) .
I wan to merge my local branch **mybranch/foo** into **foo** but to do this i have to get all those changes which have taken place in **foo** while retaining changes which i have made in **mybranch/foo** .

I have tried using 
**git rebase upstream/master** 
and
**git merge upstream/master** 
but i have not got the desired result .
but i have not got the desired result .
Above methods work for **master** of local repository but not for **mybranch/foo** .
I want to know the best way of doing this .

Answer (score 0):

`git pull`is what you are looking for:

```
git pull origin master
```

read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull) for more details.

Comment: I do not wish to pull from **origin** . I want to get updates from upstream into **mybranch/foo**

Comment: that's exactly what `git pull origin master` does. It fetches a copy of the master branch from the original remote repository, and merges it with the current branch you have checked out.

Comment: I think that `git pull origin master` fetches and merges from repository of my fork which rest on github not the repo from which i forked it ( which is denoted by **upstream**.

Comment: oh! didn't notice that **foo** was a fork, how about [syncing](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) your fork's master branch with the upstream, and then pull from it?